# Is Mapstruct capable of passing a source object to an @AfterMapping method?

Tags: java, mapstruct

Consider this code

```java
@Mapper
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class QuestionCommentMapper {
    protected final QuestionService questionService;

    public abstract QuestionComment dtoAndAuthenticationToQuestionComment(QuestionCommentRequestDto dto,
                                                                          @Context Authentication auth);

    @AfterMapping
    protected void enrichWithOwner(@MappingTarget QuestionComment questionComment, @Context Authentication auth) {
        Account owner = AuthenticationProcessor.extractAccount(auth);
        questionComment.setOwner(owner);
    }

    @AfterMapping
    protected void enrichWithQuestion(@MappingTarget QuestionComment questionComment,
                                      @Context QuestionCommentRequestDto dto) {
        Long questionId = dto.questionId();
        Question question = questionService.getById(questionId);
        questionComment.setQuestion(question);
    }
}
```

**Would Mapstruct pass a `QuestionCommentRequestDto` object to the `enrichWithQuestion()` method which is a source in the original mapping method? If not, how can I perform that second "enriching" without forgoing Mapstruct's code generation?** If I write anything in the mapping method (e.g. use the `QuestionCommentRequestDto` instance to set `QuestionComment`'s `Question` field, as in my `enrichWithQuestion()` method), Mapstruct won't generate anything, and I'll have to basically write everything manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapstruct *is* capable of that with no extra code needed. Here's the generated method

```java
@Override
    public QuestionComment dtoAndAuthenticationToQuestionComment(QuestionCommentRequestDto dto, Authentication auth) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        QuestionComment questionComment = new QuestionComment();

        questionComment.setText( dto.text() );

        enrichWithOwner( questionComment, auth );
        enrichWithQuestion( questionComment, dto ); // ← look at it

        return questionComment;
    }
```

What made me post this question was largely the fact that a chat bot said Mapstruct wouldn't pass the source object because

> Any source parameters used in the regular mapping method are not passed to the @AfterMapping method, as they are not needed for any further mapping operations at that point.

It appears the chat bot was mistaken on that